# Copy & Pasting values from one Table to another using VBA and ListObjects

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare spending data from two sources: a curated manual input from users and an automated extract, for different business units. The common data from both sources is the ID of the spending.

The idea is to aggregate both data sources (excel Tables) into one Table where the first two columns are the ID of the spending, the next column is the spending data from users related to that ID and the last one is the spending data from automated extract.

In this table, I'll have "double" the total spending for each ID, but then I can do a pivot table where I'll clearly compare the users input with the automated extract for each ID.

I highlighted the important fields I need to copy and paste.
[![PGIvsManual][3]][3]

My code is the following

```vb
Sub PGIvsManualInput()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set PGIvsManualTable = Worksheets("PGI vs Dépenses (Auto)").ListObjects("PGIvsManualInputAuto")
    Set PGITable = Worksheets("PGI Clean").ListObjects("PGIExtract")
    Set ManualInputTable = Worksheets("Dépenses").ListObjects("Dépenses")

    'Cleaning the table
    With Worksheets("PGI vs Dépenses (Auto)").Range("PGIvsManualInputAuto")
        .ClearContents
        .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    End With

    With PGIvsManualTable
        If .ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
            .DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
        End If
    End With

    'Copy the data
    PGITable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2).Copy Destination:= _
    PGIvsManualTable
```

Ant that's where it gets messy. I can't even get the first batch of data to properly import! I am trying to copy the 2 first columns from PGITable and paste them in the 2 first columns of PGIvsManualTable. This worked previously without defining any destination column in my first example, even though both the input and destination Tables didn't have the same number of columns

But in this case, it extends the pasting to all columns of my destination table! I don't understand this comportment as it doesn't happen on my previous example with basically the exact same code!!

I tried to set the destination as follows but always got errors:

```vb
PGIvsManualTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2) ==> Error 91

PGIvsManualTable.DataBodyRange(1,1) ==> Error 438

PGIvsManualTable.ListColumns(1).Resize(, 2) ==> Error 438
```

And a few others, but it never worked properly.

I expect the output  to be my selected columns copy/pasted properly in my destination column, based on the coordinates I provide in the ListObecjts.DataBodyRange.

I guess that if I manage to make this first import work, all other will work on the same template, but in the meantime, my code seem to work on the previous example.

Comment: I think the deletion `.DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete` will cause issues if you then try to paste into the `DataBodyRange` immediately after.

Comment: I removed it and used `PGIvsManualTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2)` and got the right result. How am I supposed to clean the table then?

Comment: Add a row after deleting, then you can paste.

Comment: Is there a logical reason behind that?...

Comment: A table must have a header row and one row of data, by definition. You could delete everything after row 1 instead.

Comment: Sure.. I don't get why the same piece of code works in the first example and not here but I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed you had `If .ListRows.Count >= 1 Then` so that shouldn't have been the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deletion of the `DataBodyRange.Rows` will cause an issue if you then try to paste into the `DataBodyRange`.

As a workaround, you could delete all rows after the first, something like this example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim firstTbl As ListObject, secondTbl As ListObject
    Set firstTbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    Set secondTbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2")

    With secondTbl
        .DataBodyRange.Clear

        If .ListRows.Count > 1 Then
            .DataBodyRange.Offset(1).Resize(.ListRows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete
        End If   
    End With

    firstTbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2).Copy secondTbl.DataBodyRange(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I will simplify a lot the question in order to make this answer useful, if that's alright with you